# Cannot connect to mysql using docker-compose. Connection refused error

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose

I am trying to build web application using php and mysql and running it in docker-compose.

Here is what I did:

I have made two Dockerfiles, one for php and one for mysql

**Dockerfile of PHP:**

```
FROM php:8.0-apache as base

COPY ./src /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

**Dockerfile of Mysql:**

```
FROM mysql
```

Here is my **docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    php:
        container_name: php2
        image: php
        restart: always
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerfilePHP
            target: base
        networks:
            - backend
        ports:
            - "${PHPPORT}:80"
    mysql:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerfileMysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        ports:
          - "${MYSQLPORT}:3306"
        networks:
            - backend
networks:
    backend:
      driver: bridge
```

I've specified ports in .env file:

```
PHPPORT=44445
MYSQLPORT=44446
```

[image]

and here is what in my **index.php file:**

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password');

?>
```

Here is what I get when trying to access the page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Connection refused in /var/www/html/index.php:5 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(5): mysqli->__construct('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password') #1 {main} 
thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using docker-compose to run MariaDB, InfluxDB, Grafana and some other services in one docker-compose.yaml. This is the section of MariaDB which is similar to MySQL:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Root-Passwort
      MYSQL_DATABASE: DB-Name
      MYSQL_USER: User
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: User-Passwort
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - edge
networks:
  edge: 
volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```